# How to pull a user's class type on the fly. Laravel5

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, jwt, access-token

I'd like to automatically pull user's type from:

```
dd(class_basename(JWTAuth::toUser($token)));
```

It always returns `User` even though, some users are of type `BusinessUser`.

I have setup this in my `auth.php`:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver'   => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'business_api' => [
        'driver'   => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'business_users',
    ],
],
```

I don't want to create two routes for different user types. Thus, I'd like to pull user's class on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this and let me know,

```
if ($obj instanceof YouClassName) {
// it's PDO
}
```